# Missing partial when using curl for ComfortableMexicanSofa page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I've created a partial for use in my CMS page at:

`/app/views/users/_register_home_page.html.haml`

My CMS page looks like this:

```
{{ cms:partial:/users/register_home_page }}
```

When I call this from the browser (ie, Chrome) it works fine.  Also when I go incognito (to ensure there's no cookies being sent)

calling my test page from curl:

`curl "http://localhost:5000/test"`
returns

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate at /
================================

> Missing partial users/_register_home_page with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:all], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/doug/dev/my-rails-app/app/views"

actionview (4.1.7) lib/action_view/path_set.rb, line 46
-------------------------------------------------------


   41           end
   42         METHOD
   43       end
   44   
   45       def find(*args)
>  46         find_all(*args).first || raise(MissingTemplate.new(self, *args))
   47       end
   48   
   49       def find_all(path, prefixes = [], *args)
   50         prefixes = [prefixes] if String === prefixes
   51         prefixes.each do |prefix|
```

I'd expect curl to return the same results.

**Update:** The error occurs when `Accept: text/html` is ommitted from the curl statement.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for now was to modify the CMS gem to explicitly use `:formats => [:html]` in the partial tag, and then specify the full path (including html.haml) of the partial like so:

`{{ cms:partial:/users/register_home_page.html.haml }}`

A branch where this fix is here:

https://github.com/mvcodeclub/comfortable-mexican-sofa

I've also [filed a Github issue](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/issues/547)